# Fazer uma busca no banco de dados inteiro

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

É possível fazer uma query ou existe alguma ferramenta do phpmyadmin que faça isso:

Fazer uma query no banco de dados inteiro por exemplo:

Tenho o valor `23600` e quero que ele ache essa valor no banco inteiro independente da tabela ou campo em que ele esteja.

Comment: Silvio, esse [LINK](http://fcontheweb.com/articles/search_database_with_PHP/), contém um exemplo bem detalhado de como fazer isso. O artigo está em inglês, mas é muito prático. Eu recomendo que você indexe os campos que são relativos para a pesquisa, ou seja, os que devem ser mais relevantes, para ganhar um pouco mais de performance nesse caso.

Comment: Esse vídeo ajuda a fazer essa busca de maneira inteligente , buscando em todas as colunas de todas as tabelas. https://youtu.be/r_8WYFQBTtg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No phpMyAdmin, use a funcionalidade de busca:

- Selecione o Banco de Dados
- Clique na aba de busca ("Search")
- Escolha os termos que você quer buscar
- Escolha as tabelas que quer buscar
- Go!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que é bem isso mesmo, só estou fazendo uns teste quando acabar te dou o certo.

Comment: Achei que fosse algo relacionado a sua aplicação fazer essa busca :)

Comment: Não, é somente para saber a origem de tal valor e deu certo, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('CampoParaBuscar')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='SeuBancoDeDados';
```

Comment: Pode explicar porque a sua resposta resolve o problema? para outros poderem aprender com ela

Comment: Isso só pega os nomes das tabelas.

Comment: Camila, seja bem-vinda ao [pt.so]! Fique à vontade para perguntar e responder em nossa comunidade. Porém, sugiro  procure ser mais detalhada em suas respostas, evitando apenas colocar um trecho de código, explicando com ele funciona e verificando se isso realmente responde ao que foi perguntado. Sugiro a leitura sobre [como criar uma boa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Abraço!