# É possível procurar um dado no banco de dados sem saber em qual tabela está?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um `banco de dados` muito grande e fica inviável de se construir um `SELECT * FROM` para cada tabela e localizar o dado que preciso.

> Se trata de um `texto especifico ('with as parameter 23')` já procurei de todas as maneiras e não
>   encontrei.

É possível fazer uma `query` para isso? como devo buscar? Estou usando um banco de dados relacional, em um não relacional seria mais fácil?

Comment: Isso [Fazer uma busca no banco de dados inteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10782/91)?

Comment: sim, mas no caso não uso o php my admin

Comment: Qual banco de dados você usa?

Comment: estou usando banco de dados mysql

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta que dei anteriormente.

Comment: Pode usar o workbench?

Comment: @rray posso usar, tenho ele instalado. Mas prefiro um comando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta Procedure ele procura em todos os campos que não são numéricos determinado conteúdo, primeiro parâmetro você passa o que quer buscar e no segundo o nome do banco de dados, ele vai retornar todos os resultados encontrados. em consultas separadas, porque não tem como dar um UNION ALL porque as tabelas não possuem o mesmo número de colunas. Segue o Código:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_search_data;        

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_search_data(p_conteudo TEXT,                                                                        
                                p_nome_banco TEXT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_nome_tabela TEXT;
    DECLARE v_nome_coluna TEXT;
    DECLARE v_possui_registro INT;
    DECLARE v_fim INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_tabelas CURSOR FOR SELECT  TABLE_NAME,                                                                              
                                           COLUMN_NAME
                                    FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`                                                                           
                                   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = p_nome_banco
                                     AND NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NULL;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_fim = 1;

    OPEN cur_tabelas;

    REPEAT

        IF NOT v_fim THEN
        FETCH cur_tabelas INTO v_nome_tabela, v_nome_coluna;

        SET @v_possui_registro = 0;
        SET @v_select = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @v_possui_registro
                                  FROM ',p_nome_banco,'.',v_nome_tabela,'
                                 WHERE ', v_nome_coluna,' = "',p_conteudo,'"');

        PREPARE stmt_select FROM @v_select;
        EXECUTE stmt_select;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_select;

        IF @v_possui_registro > 0 THEN

            SET @v_resultado = CONCAT('SELECT *
                                         FROM ',p_nome_banco,'.',v_nome_tabela,'
                                        WHERE ', v_nome_coluna,' = "',p_conteudo,'"');
            PREPARE stmt_resultado FROM @v_resultado;
            EXECUTE stmt_resultado;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_resultado;
                        SELECT CONCAT(p_nome_banco,'.',v_nome_tabela);
        END IF;

    END IF;
   UNTIL v_fim END REPEAT;
   CLOSE cur_tabelas;


END
|
DELIMITER ;

-- CALL sp_search_data('TESTE', 'banco_teste');
```

Lembrando que nessa procedure podem ser feitas várias implementações, como imprimir o nome da tabela e coluna que foi encontrado o registro, imprimir a query que foi feita entre outras coisas interessantes, fica ai como ideia inicial essa estrutura.

Nesse caso na primeira aba de resultado ele retorna a linha que encontrou o registro e na segunda aba a tabela.

Comment: vou testar em um banco menor, pois esse demoraria muito

Comment: Tranquilo, já testei em um banco razoavelmente grade, funciona bem. Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição. Abs